# PowerShell Test Path returns false but should be true

Tags: powershell

At the start of my PowerShell I have it checking a network location to determine if there is a newer version than the current one.  However, it will only return true if I had previously browsed to the network location.  Any suggestions, I thought about mapping a drive and then removing the drive location but I think that is a bit extreme.

```
$update=Test-Path "\\server\mylocation\Technology\Shared%20Documents\program\XXXXX.zip"
if($update -eq "True")
    {
    The rest of my code
    }
```

Comment: You need to replace the %20 with a space, as @Shay Levy pointed out, but also, have you verified the credentials the script are running under have read permissions to the resource?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace %20 with a space. %20 is used in web addresses.

Comment: still false and I tried it as SharedDocuments, Shared 20Documents, and Share Documents

Comment: I second @dugas. once you browsed to the location (and probably provided your credentials) a new session is created for you which is not avaialable when your script runs.